# Android DrawerLayout - No drawer view found with gravity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

When I click on my drawer toggle I get the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity
>   LEFT

This is my `activity_drawer.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.xyz.ui.navigation.NavigationFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My `fragment_navigation.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

</ListView>
```

And my list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_text"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: On some devices `START==LEFT` on another `==RIGHT`, it's for RTL right-to-left writting support. use everywhere `START` OR `LEFT` for fixing to chosen side on all devices

Comment: @MikeM. No, in my Java code i do not use that ;)

Comment: @Tobias : Is there any particular reason you're using a `Fragment` in your activity_drawer.xml and then simply using a layout with nothing but a `ListView` in it? What happens if you remove the `<fragment ... />` block from activity_drawer.xml and replace it with the `ListView`?

Comment: Your Drawer needs to be outside of the LinearLayout.

Comment: If you check more closely, you will notice that there are indeed two top level elements: LinearLayout and fragment.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From documentation

> To use a DrawerLayout, position your primary content view as the first child with a width and height of match_parent. Add drawers as child views after the main content view and set the layout_gravity appropriately. Drawers commonly use match_parent for height with a fixed width.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:name="com.xyz.ui.navigation.NavigationFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Simple solution and solved this error for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Ok. Let me make the things simple and clear here.
    
**What is `DrawerLayout`?**https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html

`DrawerLayout`
    Acts as a top-level container for window content that allows for
    interactive "drawer" views to be pulled out from the edge of the
    window. Drawer positioning and layout is controlled using the `android:layout_gravity`
    attribute on child views corresponding to which side of the view you
    want the drawer to emerge from: left or right. (Or start/end on
    platform versions that support layout direction.) To use a
    `DrawerLayout`, position your primary content view as the first child with a width
    and height of `match_parent`. Add drawers as child views after the main content view and set the
    `layout_gravity` appropriately. Drawers commonly use `match_parent` for height with a fixed width.

**What is `DrawerLayout`?, In Simple words:**

- The layout supported by Android that allows you to have an overlay screen, called as drawer, over your main screen.
- DrawerLayout needs childviews to work, similar to the LinearLayout and RelativeLayout.
- The childview must have either of the property set 
      
      `android:layout_gravity="start"` OR `android:layout_gravity="left"`
- DrawerLayout uses this childView to know **from where to start showing the Drawer** i.e. From Left to Right or Right to
      Left. There are countries where the text is read from Right to Left.

**Techie Stuff:**

- EVENT#1: ActionBarDrawerToggle.java is set as the drawer listener for the DrawerLayout
  ```
      DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
      ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                  toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                  R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
                  mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
  ```
- EVENT#2: The user clicks on the Toolbar.navigationIcon that calls the `toggle()` function 
      
  **ActionBarDrawerToggle.java** *(android-sdk\sources\android-22\android\support\v7\app\ActionBarDrawerToggle.java)*

  ```
      private void toggle() { 
          if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
              mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START); 
          } else {
              mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START); 
          } 
      }
  ```

  **Gravity.java** *(android-sdk\sources\android-22\android\view\Gravity.java)*

  ```
  /** Push object to x-axis position at the start of its container,
      not changing its size.*/ 
      public static final int START = RELATIVE_LAYOUT_DIRECTION | Gravity.LEFT;
  ```
- EVENT#3: `Toggle()` function calls the `mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START)`
      
      **DrawerLayout.java** (support-v4-22.1.1.jar library)

  ```
      /*** Open the specified drawer by animating it out of view. **
      @param gravity Gravity.LEFT to move the left drawer or Gravity.RIGHT
      for the right. * GravityCompat.START or GravityCompat.END may also
      be used. */ 
      public void openDrawer(@EdgeGravity int gravity) { 
          final View drawerView = findDrawerWithGravity(gravity); 
          if (drawerView == null) { 
              throw new IllegalArgumentException("No drawer view found with gravity " +
      gravityToString(gravity)); 
          }
          openDrawer(drawerView); 
      }
  ```
- EVENT#4: If no childView of the DrawerLayout is set with the `layout_gravity="start”` or `left` the `No drawer view found with gravity LEFT` is thrown.

**Solution:**

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <!--This will appear when the drawer is closed (default view)--> 
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"> 
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" /> 
    </LinearLayout> 
    <!-- This will appear when the drawer is opened -->
    <!-- the property,android:layout_gravity, is used internally to identify imageView as the view to be displayed when the drawer is opened -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height=" match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/img_shree_ganesha" /> 

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
I hope that helps. Happy Coding…
```

Answer (score 10):

The "Android Drawer" needs to be a direct child node of the "DrawerLayout".

In your example above (re: original question example), you only have a single direct child node under "DrawerLayout" ("LinearLayout"), and **no drawer view** after it.

Move your drawer view out of your LinearLayout and place it after it.

Answer (score 4):

in my case, because DrawerLayout attr: `tools:openDrawer="start"`
i added `android:layout_gravity="start"` for the second element

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="right"
    tools:context=".map.MapFragment">

<include layout="@layout/fragment_map" />

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_nav_header"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was missing. Without the tools:openDrawer matching the navigationView layout_gravity, I received crashes as per the original post.

Answer (score 4):

add

android:layout_gravity="start"

to NavigationView

like this

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_menu"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:foregroundGravity="right"
    android:id="@+id/nv">

    <include layout="@layout/drawer_menu"/>
</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using right to left(RTL) layout? Setting gravity left on RTL layout would throw this exception. This can be fixed by setting gravity start instead of left

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem like this :

**XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    tools:openDrawer="end"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**AND IN JAVA:**

```
 if (mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    }
```

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the same gravity in DrawerLayout and NavigationView: for example: tools:openDrawer="right"in DrawerLayout tag and android:layout_gravity="right" in NavigationView tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="right"
    tools:context=".map.MapFragment">

<include layout="@layout/fragment_map" />
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_nav_header"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT**

**SOLUTION**
Assign a **layout_gravity = "start" or "left"** attribute to one of your DrawerLayout child view if your drawer layout already have a child view. OR
Simply create a child view inside your DrawerLayout View and give it a **layout_gravity = "start" or "left"** attribute.
        for example

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mDrawer_Layout"
        tools:context="com.rad5.matdesign.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
                android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                tools:openDrawer="start">

    <!-- Notice that here an image view as a child of the Drawer layout was -->
    <!-- given a layout_gravity="start" -->

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"/>

            </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_items" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error fixed after replacing

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.MyFragment"/>
```

with

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />
```

and added Fragment instance to the FragmentContainerView in onCreate()

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.fragmentContainerView, MyFragment())
    .commit()
```