# No drawer view found with gravity LEFT

Tags: android, material-design

When I run the app and click on the toolbar icon I get the error as " No drawer view found with gravity LEFT"

this is my xml file

**main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/book_list_rv_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ListView1"
            android:layout_width="241dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#333"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#666"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15sp"
            android:paddingRight="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

this id the code snippet of the activity java file
**activity file**

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // drawer
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                mToolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Comment: u can this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706552/no-more-allow-open-drawer-layout-from-right-side-in-navigation-drawer/30738746#30738746

thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android DrawerLayout - No drawer view found with gravity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350136/android-drawerlayout-no-drawer-view-found-with-gravity)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Content and Drawer must be two children of the DrawerLayout. So change your layout like that:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/book_list_rv_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView1"
        android:layout_width="241dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#333"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#666"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15sp"
        android:paddingRight="15sp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 9):

First set drawerlayout then set support action bar.
Check following code.

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
 mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
 mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                mToolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
 mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
 setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);//modified(changed line)
```

Comment: This brings drawer to right but the Menu (hamburger icon) is still on right. Can you please help

Comment: can u post your xml file.

Comment: i've been looking for all the answers this one is my answer. thanks.

Answer (score 8):

it may be related the way you try close drawer

```
mToolBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.Start)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.Start);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.Start);
        }
    }
```

for more reference

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/GravityCompat.html#START

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my case, I enabled `android:supportRtl=true` in `AndroidMainifest.xml`. And in code, I used `mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)` instead of `Gravity.START`. Once i have replaced all these Gravity.LEFT and Gravity.RIGHT. There are no more this error.

Answer (score -1):

Content and drawer should be in different layouts, and drawer should have gravity left.

> DrawerLayout
>
> Contnet
>
> Drawer
>
> /DrawerLayout

Update your file like this,

```
<LinearLayout ....
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/book_list_rv_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ListView1"
            android:layout_width="241dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left" //or start
            android:background="#333"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#666"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15sp"
            android:paddingRight="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```