# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: due to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer on Redmi devices

Tags: android

I have a toolbar with menu icon and I have attached a click on the menu which opens the left drawer.

I have tested on multiple devices without any issues. But on Play Store I see crashes due to this. The effected devices on Redmi Note 4 and 5.

Complete log below.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer (DrawerLayout.java:1618)
  at gamesmint.com.jsone.NewLayoutActivity$1.onClick (NewLayoutActivity.java:199)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:6304)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:24803)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:790)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6600)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:518)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:821)
```

Comment: What version of Android is Redmi Note 4 and 5 running? Do you have more code you can show us? Can you show us the line of code #199 in `NewLayoutActivity` and the surrounding code?

Comment: The Android version is 7 and 8.1. The code Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // perform whatever you want on back arrow click
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        });

Answer (score 1):

If the error is

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT

you can hava a try like this:

The childview of DrawerLayout must have either of the property set 
`android:layout_gravity="start"` OR `android:layout_gravity="left"`. If you have set `left` or `right`, you can replace them with  `start` or `end`.

And I hope you can show us the code the next time.

Comment: I have put layout_gravity as left|start on my child view which is a ListView. Is this the probable issue?

Comment: @SPS [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350136/android-drawerlayout-no-drawer-view-found-with-gravity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350136/android-drawerlayout-no-drawer-view-found-with-gravity)  hope the answer can help you